# CakePHP 2.x .htaccess: Get 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, internal-server-error

**Problem solved**

1. Changed all folder and file permissions to 755
2. All .htaccess files
   with absolute paths (/app/webroot/)

---

I moved my CakePHP 2.x website to another hoster (cyon.ch). Now i got 500 Internal Server Error. I tryed all the fixed who are recommended for the 1and1 hoster, but they won't work.

The error comes from the /app/webroot/.htacces file, cause the others seems to work. If i try to call a image from the webroot/img directory, it works fine (www.myDomain.ch/img/myPicture.jpg), but not the index.php file.

```
AddType text/x-component .htc

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # FORCE WWW
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.myDomain\.ch$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.myDomain.ch/$1 [R=301,L]

    # REMOVE TRAILING SLASHES
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

The "FORCE WWW" and "REMOVE TRAILING SLASHED" are ok as well, if i type myDomain.ch/, i'll got redirect to www.myDomain.ch.

My Domain points to /path/to/root/public_html. Thats also the folder, in which the cake app folder is located.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I found this error in the error log (Permissions for index.php are set to 755)

```
SoftException in Application.cpp:256: File "/home/myUsername/public_html/app/webroot/index.php" is writeable by group
```